# Develop animated button in android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-button

Please refer the attached picture when user click on GO button all the other button comes under the GO button and when user again clicks the GO button all the buttons get distributed. I want to make same button and animation. I searched a lot but not got anything relevant, Kindly help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [satellite menu library](https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu), with this you can acheive as you want. In this you need to handle the position of it.